# The function of a new new class object; error: A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a function of hiring (create a new class object) a new employee. I've decided to use default constructor (if is not it good decision please correct me). I've got the error with `Employee::Hire(employees);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Employee
{
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    Employee::Employee()
    {

        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }

    void Employ(std::vector<Employee> &v)
    {
        v.push_back(Employee());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> employees;

    Employee::Employ(employees);

    system("pause");
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `::Hire` would work if `Hire` was a `static` function. What you're trying to do really isn't clear from the code, let alone the naming.

Comment: You seem to have a very deep misunderstanding how classes (or any object really) work in C++. You should read a good book or tutorial.

Comment: I've just started to code the program. English is not my native language and while coding I've thought that employ == hire. I've forgotten to correct it, sorry.

Comment: You say " I've got the error with Employee::Hire(employees);" , but there is no `Hire` in the code

Comment: @Baum mit Augen it might be true. Do you recommend to let it go and start from the begin?

Comment: @M.M I've just edited it. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar `static void Employ(std::vector<Employee> &v)` works properly but I'm wondering does it correct. I mean: do I should use it?

Comment: @mathsicist Well, whatever you mean with *"from the beginning"*. What you know now will not just vanish. However, guessing does not serve you well in C++, so if you don't know a concept yet, look it up in a good source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function:

```
void Employ(std::vector<Employee> &v)
{
    v.push_back(Employee());
}
```

should be moved out of the class definition of `Employee`.  Member functions operate on an instance of the class, but you intend to call it without any instance.

Alternatively the function could be made `static` , however IMHO the preferred style is to just use a non-member.